# Best opcode cache for fcgid? (APC vs eaccelerator vs xcache)

Tags: cache, mod-fcgid, alternative-php-cache, php, xcache

I have been reading a while the web trying to find out about opcode caches for fcgid. As I understand so far APC is not a good solution for fcgid, since APC with fcgid caches only per process and that is inefficient. (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598444/how-to-share-apc-cache-between-several-php-processes-when-running-under-fastcgi)

So I guess that leaves eaccelerator and xcache. [Xcache seems to talk explicitly about fcgid](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs:PerformanceFastCGI#Installing-XCache) so I am leaning towards that. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Installed APC and it seems to be working fine. Also, it seems the cache is not per process, and I am seeing > 90% utilization. Good Stuff

Comment: If you are using fcgid then there are multiple caches of the same script, which partially defeats the purpose of using an opcode cache and wastes memory. You should be using php-fpm and/or Apache 2.4 to properly use an opcode cache.